# Scraping Multiple Tables with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a python newbie trying to scrape tables with Beautiful Soup.

I want to scrape tables similar to the one below with Ubuntu CVE information and output the table to a csv document.

```
<div class="pkg">
<div class="field">Package</div><div class="value">Source: <a href="http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/mysql-cluster-7.0.html">mysql-cluster-7.0</a></div>
<table>
<tr><td>(Lucid Lynx):</td><td>ignored
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Precise Pangolin):</td><td>DNE
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Quantal Quetzal):</td><td>DNE
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Raring Ringtail):</td><td>DNE
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Saucy Salamander):</td><td>DNE
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="pkg">
<div class="field">Package</div><div class="value"><a href="http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/mysql-5.5.html">mysql-5.5</a></div>
<table>
<tr><td>(Lucid Lynx):</td><td>DNE
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Precise Pangolin):</td><td>released
(5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Quantal Quetzal):</td><td>released
(5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.10.1)
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Raring Ringtail):</td><td>released
(5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1)
</td></tr>
<tr><td>(Saucy Salamander):</td><td>released
(5.5.32-0ubuntu1)
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want the csv output to be in this format:

1. release, status
2. (Lucid Lynx),ignored
3. (Precise Pangolin),DNE
4. etc....

I can pull all the tables with `table = soup.findAll("table")`But I'm unsure of how to split the contents of all the table into two different cells onto a spreadsheet.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try yourself with table('tr') to track the row and then followed by row('td') to locate and extract the content you want. then put them into csv format by using csv lib. If meet any problem, then ask

Answer (score 1):

First, your file  appears to be valid XML, so you should just use the normal XML parsing in python. Beautiful Soup is not needed at all.

That said, you will really want to find_all rows, loop over them, and join the columns.

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['release', 'status'])
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        writer.writerow(col.string for col in row.find_all('td'))
```

Comment: Was this the question? No!

Comment: Chill, I gave the answer as well, whats the issue?